# Nuget Restore failure in Azure Functions on a docker container-

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, nuget, azure-functions-core-tools

I am having problems with my docker build script for a basic Azure Function.  I have been following this blog post:
https://medium.com/@adrianromanin/azure-functions-on-a-docker-container-7b00d2c36eb2

At the point of the nuget restore I get the following errors:

> Restoring packages for
>   C:\src\dotnet-function-app\functionsanddockerdemo.csproj... C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.403\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to load
>   the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
>   [C:\src\dotnet-function-app\functionsanddockerdemo.csproj] C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.403\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond
>   [C:\src\dotnet-function-app\functionsanddockerdemo.csproj] The command
>   'cmd /S /C dotnet restore
>   src/dotnet-function-app/functionsanddockerdemo.csproj -s
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json' returned a non-zero code: 1

My docker build script:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS installer-env

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app

RUN mkdir "home/site/wwwroot/"
RUN dir "C:/src/dotnet-function-app"

RUN dotnet publish src/dotnet-function-app/functionsanddockerdemo.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot
```

I've tried explicitly specifiying package restore via both of these commands:

```
RUN dotnet restore src/dotnet-function-app/functionsanddockerdemo.csproj -s https://api.nuget.org/v#3/index.json

RUN dotnet restore src/dotnet-function-app/functionsanddockerdemo.csproj --verbosity diag
```

However they both give the same result. I initially thought maybe my container didn't have any network connectivity, however I have connectivty confirming via:

RUN ping www.google.co.uk

My docker info:

```
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 17134 (17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804)
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.285)
```

I am sure I hav missed something basic here!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm running into the same exact message when trying to run it on my local machine.

Comment: Hi, yes was working through all configuration and setup with no luck. Then I thought I would disable my AVG and then it all worked. So its the firewall that was blocking the download.

Comment: I've set up a build in VSTS where it works, so it really is on my local machine. It's very bizarre as this has never happened before. I'll try disable the windows firewall and try again. Thanks for your reply @SimonNet.

Comment: Here's what eventually fixed the problem:
Delete the Nuget.xml file in your appdata as described here
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2880